# Div height not adapting to parent

Tags: html, css

Still developing my html5/css3 mobile site, I have trouble adjusting the height of a div to its parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/1eg2cwLs/

[image: Actual screenshot]

The fiddle doesn't exactly look like this because I'm using webfonts (saved offline though as I'm not going to have internet connection on the target system). But the problem remains the same.

You might be seeing what the problem is right from the spot, if not: I would like the green and red bar (`.itemclass`) always have the same size as the content of its parent (`.item`).

Depending on font, its size (still playing around with it) and the overall height of each item, I have to precisely adjust the negative margin. Otherwise it looks like in the screenshot. The negative margin I just mentioned is in the CSS-class `.itemclass`: (marked with an arrow also in the fiddle)...

```
.itemclass {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #27ae60;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: -27px; /* <=== */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This cannot be the solution. I tried a lot of stuff and I only got it "working" the way I mentioned.

Any better idea how to make it look clean without a hack?

As well, tips for other improvements regarding my html/css are well appreciated.

Sorry for appending the entire code into the fiddle. I don't know whether it was representative if I was going to remove stuff.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably go this route:

```
.item {
    position: relative;
    ...
}
.itemclass {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    ...
}
.itemcontent {
    margin-left: 50px;
    ...
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/1eg2cwLs/3/)

[**Really big font demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/1eg2cwLs/4/)

Consider a reasonable min-width for the body to prevent `.tagline` from overlapping, etc.

Comment: This sounds like a plan, thank you. What about the icons on the right if you remove `font-size` at all? The item's height becomes too small so that parts of it is cut.

Comment: And I see one more "problem" there: If the font and/or content is quite small, the icons (top of item) overlap with the category (bottom). How to do it better? Thank you!

Comment: You'll need to wrap and/or position those items in a similar manner. That's probably outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can set .item's margin-top to 0, and instead adjust the margin-top of .vcenter:before. This way you're just adjusting the text and not the div.

Or you could drop the static height and width of .itemclass altogether. Now the .itemclass will scale.
http://jsfiddle.net/1eg2cwLs/5/

```
.item {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.itemclass {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #27ae60;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-top: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

As a fallback, you can set .item to not show overflow, and then adjust the line-height of :

```
 .item {overflow:hidden}
```

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden;` is your best friend in this case! It hides any overflow content from view outside of `.item`

Add it into `.item {}` declaration.

http://jsfiddle.net/1eg2cwLs/1/

Comment: This works up to the point that `.itemclass` has less height than `.item`. Try a large font size on `.itemcontent`.

Comment: Yes, good point, but this resolves the OP's stated question. I saw no mention of large font size.